# How do I change the currency symbol in Magento 1.5.1.0?

Tags: magento, locale, currency

I'm trying to change the price format in Magento ver. 1.5.1.0 from
€8.49
to EUR 8.49

I have been looking through lots of posts and forums but it didn't work out.
I tried to follow the instructions but it didn't work out so far.
Cache is deactivated.

```
/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml
<currency type="EUR">
 <displayName>Euro</displayName>
 <displayName count="one">euro</displayName>
 <displayName count="other">euros</displayName>
 //added <symbol>EUR</symbol> here
</currency>

/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/root.xml
<currency type="EUR">
  <symbol>€</symbol> => changed to <symbol>EUR</symbol> didn't work
</currency>
```

And no, i don't want to change the core /Zend files or use str_replace.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to grep in your version root and you'll see that it is locale based so you just might need to change t in multiple files.

```
grep 'type="EUR"' . -rsn
```

don't forget to clear cache afterwards before observing the changes in front-end

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Removing the /var/cache made it. Didn't know that the deactivated Cache is not enough...

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use free extension [Currency Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/niro/extension/5823/et_currencymanager)
2. Or you can write your own simple module and override function format() in Mage_Directory_Model_Currency model.

   ```
   public function formatTxt($price, $options=array())
   {
       $options['display'] = Zend_Currency::USE_SHORTNAME;
       return parent::formatTxt($price, $options);
   }
   ```

P.S. You can loose your changes in /lib/Zend/Locale/Data/*.xml files after Magento upgrade.

Comment: well you can always move the changed file to app/code/local/Zend/Locale/Data but yes you must keep track on any local changes

Comment: @AntonS seems like this method doesn't work. Just take a look at Zend_Locale_Data::_findRoute method: it is looking for locate files in such way: $filename = dirname(__FILE__) . '/Data/' . $locale . '.xml'; - that means, that file always will be loaded from lib/Zend/Locale/Data directory

Comment: @Snowcore have you tried this as well? Magento allows you to override Zend files. So you can either override the path or see if it is done for you already

Comment: @AntonS yes, I know. But it allows to override php files only, this trick doesn't work for Zend's xml files.

Comment: @Snowcore :) rewrite the Zend_Locale_Data::_findRoute in local scope to get where you need to get and that way you can rewrite the xml files as well

Comment: @AntonS yes, this is the most appropriate way to achieve this. It's pity that we can't simply copy xml file from lib to local code pool :(

Comment: @Snowcore if you bother then file a bug or patch to zend_fw issues list to make that path configurable